# sharing cookies across domains on same host

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to maintain a web site spread across two domains with the same host (one is actually in a subfolder of the other):

```
www.a.com  -> /.../public_html/
www.b.com  -> /.../public_html/b/
```

I have one script on a.com, let's call it `public_html/readcookiedata.php`, which reads in some session variables from a cookie. Another script on b.com, let's say `public_html/b/index.php`, needs to also read this cookie.

Right now `index.php` tries to `require_once(../readcookiedata.php)`.

This works great if I visit `www.a.com/b/index.php`: the cookie is read OK.
However, if I browse to there directly, `www.b.com/index.php`, the cookie isn't read.

What's the best way to fix this problem? Is there a way for a.com to allow b.com to read its cookies? Or some way to configure the host to treat all requests to b.com as if they were for a.com/b/ instead?

Comment: I think you have the same situation as stackoverflow portal - they have many domains and each requires authorisation. You can do it the same way as they did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Cookie security is built into the web at a browser level; browsers literally *won't allow* you to read data for cookies from other domains on pages served by a different domain.

Comment: What's the best workaround? For instance, I suppose I could include a frame on b.com containing a script on a.com that reads the cookie and stores the data in a shared database, and then read the database from b.com, but surely there's a better way?

Comment: What you're basically doing is trying to create a cross-site request chain, which is basically asking to be the victim of an XSS attack. The `iframe` approach is your best bet for something that's actually reasonably secure, since the data-sharing is done on your backend.