# session sharing on multiple domain but same ip address in tomcat

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I have two domains one is `example.com` and the second in `mydomain.com` both domain is hosted in same ip address. I have a feature like add to cart in the website and it is stored in session. When i store values in session in `example.com` and i got to the `mydomain.com` the session not getting in `mydomain.com` domain. Here the problem is domain name is different but both the domain loading the same content or same ip. On close looking i can find the `jsessionid` generated for the different domain are different. So my question is, is there any way to share the session between two domain? Is this issue will be fixed by making the `jsessionid` same for both domain? I have implemented my project in struts framework in java.

Comment: The session is stored in a cookie. So according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908002/sharing-cookies-across-domains-on-same-host you cannot use the same cookie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406719/cookies-set-across-multiple-domains indicates that you might be able to use JavaScript to synchronize cookies between domains.

Comment: Yes i got the solution on same way..